# Arduino Shield on Breadboard

Tags: adafruit, rfid

I would like to ask if I can stack directly Adafruit PN532 RFID Shield onto my breadboard. Or do I need something for that? Thank you.

Comment: no, but shields typically only use a portion of the pins, the rest are passed-through; this means a few dupont connectors can get a shield up and running; no need to connect "extra" pins" for the shield "top"

Answer (score 3):

Chances are the offset headers won't allow the shield to directly plug into a breadboard.

As @Majenko noted, shields have a header that is offset by 0.16" from the other headers. Since a breadboard is a strict 0.1" grid that header won't fit into the holes.

Answer (score 1):

@Mazaryk is right.

Shields have a header that is offset by 0.16" from the other headers. Since a breadboard is a strict 0.1" grid that header won't fit into the holes.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [Kickstarter project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/818225433/breadboard-shield-adapter-for-microcontrollers-or) a few years ago to make just such an adapter. You might get in touch with the developer to find out whether he's made (or is planning) another run.